# SVG link a PNG bitmap image ignoring transparency (without path)

Tags: html, svg, bitmap, transparency

I'm having difficulties with an image map-like approach for linking an image but ignoring its transparent areas. Imagine that I have a PNG button with rounded corners (bad example for simplicity's sake, I know about CSS's border-radius), and I only want to have the cursor change on the button itself, ignoring its transparency.

Of course I could just do it like this:

```
<image width="438" height="189" xlink:href="button.png"></image>
<a xlink:href="//google.com/">
    <path id="ab" d="M351.371,342.397c-55 …" />
</a>
```

But what if I want to do that dynamically e.g. having a JS function generating the markup for different-sized images using the same technique? Maybe using an SVG mask?

The following snippet of course links the whole image...

```
<a xlink:href="//google.com">
    <image width="438" height="189" xlink:href="button.png"></image>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have come across a couple of questions here on SO with png images in svg.
There seems to be little support for this in a couple of browsers. I don't have the time to test all major browsers atm.

But your trying to create a button with rounded corns that's only clickable on the painted area, not the transparent part?
Why not use svg rect to create that button?

```css
svg text {
  fill: white;
}
svg rect {
  fill: firebrick;
  stroke: gray;
}
svg a:active rect {
  stroke: black;
}
svg a:active text {
  text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="50%">
  <a xlink:href="#">
    <rect x="20" y="30" width="70" rx="5" height="30" />
    <text x="30" y="50">Submit</text>
  </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: The button is only an example to show what I'm looking for. Of course there are numerous ways to make that button, but what if it's a vector shape not easily recreatable?

Comment: There are not a lot of shapes that can be created with svg. I'll admit there could be limitations, but you would get a shape really close with svg.

Comment: Yeah, you could probably describe any shape with a polygon tag. But I want to achieve the same effect without having to describe any coordinates. Sort of like the magic wand in photoshop: remove any transparent pixels from the link area.

Comment: There could be a way to do it with clip-path but its probably limited and bad browser support. SVG has a lot better for selecting shapes. Since this feature is basically default in all svg shapes.